# C++ float value of a local variable explanation?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a simple math vector struct

```
struct vec3d {
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
  float w;
public:
  vec3d(float a, float b, float c) { a = x; b = y; c = z; w = 1; }
  vec3d() { x = 0; y = 0; z = 0; w = 1; }
};
```

With the following operation in a function (I am not using operator overloading)

```
vec3d vsubvector(vec3d& v1, vec3d& v2)
{
  return vec3d(v1.x - v2.x, v1.y - v2.y,v1.z - v2.z);
}
```

I am using it inside the main function within a loop block like this

```
{
...
            vec3d normal, line1, line2;

            line1 = vsubvector(p[1], p[0]);
            line2 = vsubvector(p[2], p[0]);

            normal = vcrossproduct(line1, line2);
            normal = vnormalise(normal);
...
}
```

Here *p* is an array of three vectors

Now while debugging, when I enter the block where the local variable is defined, line1.x, line1.y and line1.z are assigned a big signed float value (-107374176.0f) and they do not change after the subtract function is returned into them.

What is the reason that vsubvector function is not working?

Comment: Yes you should reverse assignments in `a = x; b = y; c = z; w = 1;`

Comment: `vec3d(float a, float b, float c) { a = x; b = y; c = z; w = 1; }` - No. Don't do that. *Initialize* variables. Don't first default construct them and then assign to them. You also got the assignment order wrong. Do this instead: `vec3d(float a, float b, float c) : x(a), y(b), z(c), w(1) { }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vec3d(float a, float b, float c) { a = x; b = y; c = z; w = 1; }
```

Is assigning to the constructor arguments from the uninitialised member variables. Obviously wrong. You'd want to reverse the order of assignment.

Additionally, you should use the constructors initialization list to initialize members rather than the constructor body. Do this:

```
vec3d(float a, float b, float c) : x(a), y(b), z(c), w(1) { }
```

For basic types like `int`s or `float`s it makes little difference, but for user defined types it can make a big difference. It is wasteful to first let the constructor default initialize members and then subsequently assign to them in the constructor body. Also, for some types, doing so is not even possible, not all types support assignment so initialization is the only option.

Additionally, the default constructor `vec3d()` can delegate to the other constructor:

```
vec3d() : vec3d(0.f, 0.f, 0.f) {}
```

Comment: Correct. To make explicit why it's such good advice: the compiler will complain if you accidentally write `vec3d(float a, float b, float c) : a(x), b(y), c(z), w(1) { }`. It will tell you that `a` is not a member of `vec3d`.